# Flash Video Displaying Wonky in WinForms WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, winforms, flash, webbrowser-control

Here is the issue. I'm making a web browser for my 3 year old so that I can specify which sites he can go to and make it easy for him to get to those sites. One of the sites that I have specified is the Disney Junior site. http://disney.go.com/disneyjunior  However, when I load up that site in the WebBrowser control the flash is kinda wonky. This is the only flash site that does this. The top and side nav are like twice the size they should be.  This has happened on multiple machines, so it's not just my dev box. Also, the site looks just fine in IE9. I've been pulling my hair out trying to figure out what is happening, but I'm running dry on ideas. At first I though it had something to do with zoom in IE, so I created a new control inherited from the WebBrowser control and added a zoom property, but that didn't fix it. Then I thought maybe the User Agent string might be an issue so I tried modifying it to no avail ... plus it turns out that the WebBrowser control identifies itself as IE9 anyway ... so that's not it. I've thought about using GeckoFX or Webkit.NET, but those projects are both way out of date, so I would rather use something more modern like the built in IE control (ironic, I know).  Plus there would just be less external dependencies.

The way to repilcate this issue is simply...

```
 1. Create a new winform project
 2. Drop a WebBrowser control on the form and dock it full to the winform
 3. In the form onload event add this code... webBrowser1.Navigate(@"http://disney.go.com/disneyjunior");
 4. When the site opens up it will probably look normal, but give it an F5
    refresh and you should see the nav go wonky...and it will stay that
    way ... forever ... even the next time you restart the project (possibly a cache issue?)
```

Any thoughts on things to try or solutions would be much appreciated. I'm up for doing the coding, but at this point I'm stumped as to what might be happening, so I thought I would appeal to those smarter than me.

Comment: I followed your repro steps and I get a 100% green screen in the webbrowser control followed by a "An Error has occured in the page" Line 257, Char 60 - Object Expected, Do you want to continue Running scripts on this page. I click Yes and nothing, still green, no mickeymouse loading as per running webpage on Chrome

Comment: +1 for the idea of creating a browser to control your kids web content. Next week I'll test that and see if I can spot something. I'd also like to ask you if you'd mind sharing your source code if you made a kid-oriented design. I have a couple of kids that will get introduced to the internet soon, it would be a great tool ;D

Comment: In my experience, WinForms is pretty rough with its ActiveX controls (of which Flash is one of them). I was doing a bit of work in that early in my project, and I hit a LOT of errors. Not to be a "programmaticus takeoveriticus", but if you run into too many issues, research Python for this purpose.

Comment: This seems to work fine in my case. This sounds more like en environment issue to me. I have worked extensively with the browser control and it certainly has it's quirks. I am running Windows 7 64 Bit Ultimate with VS 2010 Ultimate fully updated. What versions are you using and more importantly, do you use IE as your primary browser?

Comment: I've done a bunch of searching and it looks like the web browser control has some issues with cross domain resources and caching. I'm not sure it can be worked around. So, I dumped the native webrowser control and went with gecko and a .NET wrapper called GeckoFX. The source code for the browser is up on bitbucket (https://bitbucket.org/fredclown/kidbrowser). I've also got a compiled version linked off of this post (http://thestuders.blogspot.com/2011/12/kid-browser.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've done a bunch of searching and it looks like the web browser control has some issues with cross domain resources and caching. I'm not sure that it can be worked around. So, I dumped the native webrowser control and went with gecko and a .NET wrapper called GeckoFX. If you have an answer for this I will transfer the accepted answer check to your answer.